# I can't get scrollspy to work with my bootstrap navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I know this is a very common problem, but I have spent ~two days crawling the forums, trying fixes, can't seem to find the answer.

I have a standard bootstrap setup that uses some parallax scrolling. I have a navbar fixed to the bottom of the page. Each `<li>` is shaped like a circle, and inside the `<li>` is an `<a>` tag. Each 'circular' `<li>` is linked to an anchor tag on the page in order to provide navigation around the page. This is a one-page template set up.

Here is a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/k8g3qydw/1/

I have the bootstrap.css and .js files properly enqueued, I added `data-target=".scrollspy" data-spy="scroll" data-offset="0"`
to the `body` tag and added the class `.scrollspy` to the parent element of my `<ul>` like so:

```
<div class="scrollspy board-inner">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
        <div class="liner"></div>
            <li class="nav-item active">
```

So, I am pretty confused as to what to do!

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple mistakes in your code.

1. You should use one method to add Bootstrap ScrollSpy to your page, not both:
   via Data Attributes **or** JavaScript. So you should delete your body attributes or javasript line `$('body').scrollSpy({...});`
2. ID attribute must be unique to the whole document. You have repeated IDs on page. And.. In wrong place. On working fiddle #spy was assigned to nav wrapper, since it is the one which is being spied.
3. Navbar links should point to "resolvable id targets" instead of `<a name="service">`. You should use `<a id="service">`.
4. And also make sure that `bootstrap.min.js` is included after `jQuery` in your document. Since jQuery is required for Bootstrap, not other way.

Here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aBiscuit/pfeyrwo4/)